# Shortest possible comparison sequence to determine order of elements

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Supposed you have $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\rangle$ = $\langle 6,16,13,9,6\rangle$, how would you find a shortest possible sequence of comparisons that determines the order of elements?

Comment: The question is rather unclear.  Are you interested in this specific sequence or in sequences in general? For a single sequence, brute force always gives an answer in constant time.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Did you do any research in the literature? Hint: (optimal) sorting networks.

Answer (score 1):

### It is necessary and sufficient to do $n-1$ comparisons.

You just order indices according to the order of corresponding values,
noting equalities.

If you choose increasing order, that gives for the example:
 1 = 5 < 4 < 3 < 2

Then you chose the sequence of comparisons tests that tests precisely
these equalities or inequalities. And that sequence is precisely exactly what you
need to make a decision regarding the order. It uses $n-1$
comparisons (i.e., $n-1$ comparisons are sufficient), but it can be proved
that less would not be enough (so that $n-1$ comparisons are
necessary). Hence the sequence of tests is optimal, i.e. shortest.

The proof that $n-1$ comparisons are necessary can be done by
induction on $n$.

It is clearly true for $n=1$ and for $n=2$. In the latter case, the
only way to order the two elements is to compare them.

Now we only need the following lemma.

*Lemma*: If $n$ elements can always be ordered with $m$ comparisons,
then $n-1$ elements can always be ordered with $m-1$ comparisons.

If we consider $n-1$ elements, there is an integer $a$ that is greater
than all of them. Then consider the problem of ordering all the same
elements with $a$ included. This can be done with $m$ comparisons by
hypothesis. At least one of these comparisons must be with $a$, since
otherwise we could get the same order with $a$ as greatest element,
even if we had chosen $a$ smallest. The value of $a$ has to be tested
at least once.

But this comparison is irrelevant for ordering the initial $n-1$
elements, since it involves only one of them, So the proper ordering
of these $n-1$ elements can be achieved with at most $m-1$ tests.

Using this lemma, we prove that if $n$ elements can be ordered with
less than $n-1$ comparisons, then $2$ elements can be ordered without
any comparison, which is false. Hence $n-1$ comparisons are necessary.

Comment: You should probably mention the $\Theta(n\log n)$ lower bound for comparison-based sorting and explain how your answer doesn't contradict this. The question asks how to *find* the optimal sequence and doing that with a comparison-based sorting algorithm sequence requires either $\Theta(n\log n)$ comparisons or a sorting algorithm that's not based on comparisons. The optimal sequence itself only has length $n-1$.

Comment: (And how would you do non-comparison-based sorting without an *a priori* bound on the magnitudes of the sequence elements?)